# Obtains character with string Substring()

Tags: c#, substring

I need obtains some character from the names of a images, the format of that names is:

`141000000005.jpg`, `141000150005.jpg`, `141004600007.jpg`...etc. I make the `split()` to separe the `".jpg"`, now I need obtains the character from the position 3 to 10, for example:

```
141000000005 --> 00000000

141000150005 --> 00015000

141004600007 --> 00460000
```

The names images comes in a `List<string>`, so I in this moment I make this:

```
    char[] timeCodeArray = timeCodeList[i].ToCharArray();
    string timeCodeArrayString = Convert.ToString(timeCodeArray[3].ToString() +  
        timeCodeArray[4].ToString() + timeCodeArray[5].ToString() + timeCodeArray[6].ToString() + 
        timeCodeArray[7].ToString() + timeCodeArray[8].ToString() + timeCodeArray[9].ToString() + 
        timeCodeArray[10].ToString());
```

How can I make this with substring??

Comment: do format your code, also use System.IO.Path to strip the extension (GetFileNameWithoutExtension)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var timeCodeArrayString = timeCodeList[i].Substring(3,8)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String substr = "141000000005".Substring(3, 8);
```

Answer (score 1):

mystring.Substring(3,7) -> return a string which starts at character 3 and take 7 charcaters

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want `myString.Substring(3,8)`

Just for reference, though it's a lousy solution for this particular problem, if you concatenate lots of strings with '+', you get a string, so you don't need to call Convert.ToString on the result.